# saving random images in separate folder in python

Tags: python, listdir

I am facing a little problem,
actually I have a function which generates so many frames from a video that I provided to my code which then saves in a specific folder , then I access some frames from that folder by using RND (random ) command , now what I want is that those random frames which my code pick randomly should also save in some other folder, for example, if there are 300 frames and my code pick 15 frames randomly from those 300 frames then these 15 frames must also save in some other separate folder .
This is my code,

```
def video_frames(nameof_video,frame_savelocation,cropimages_save):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(nameof_video)
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    print(success)

    count = 1
    success = True
    while success:
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        cv2.imwrite(frame_savelocation+"/%d.jpg" % count, image)
        # save frame as JPEG file
        # if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
        #   break
        if count == 0:
            break
        count += 1
    print("frames saved in the desired location!!!!!")
        ##### crop faces from frame and save them----###
    for r in range(1, 15):
        random_imagecrop(frame_savelocation, cropimages_save)  #-----> function called
    return

def random_imagecrop(frame_savelocation,cropimages_save):
    #b=1
    crop_faces_path = frame_savelocation
    list_frames = os.listdir(crop_faces_path)  # dir is your directory path
    number_files = len(list_frames)

    rnd = random.randint(1, number_files)
    print("random:", rnd)
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(frame_savelocation + "/" + str(rnd) + ".jpg")
    #pil_image.save("Datasets/randomimg" + "/" + str(b) + ".jpg")
    #b=b+1
    # Find all the faces in the image
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)



    check = os.listdir(cropimages_save)  # dir is your directory path
    already_prsntimg = len(check)

    a = 1+already_prsntimg
    for face_location in face_locations:
    # Print the location of each face in this image
        top, right, bottom, left = face_location
        # print("A face is located at pixel location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

         # You can access the actual face itself like this:
        face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
         # pil_image.show()
        pil_image.save(cropimages_save + "/" + str(a) + ".jpg")
        a = a + 1
    print("--> Images saved successfully...!!!")
        # a=a+len(face_locations)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir('output')` to change the working directory to the output directory and then write the image. Then to return to the original directory to pick your random images use `os.chdir('../')`.

Comment: Although it should work in practice, I wouldnt recommend it. Python comes with a huge library for path management `os.path` just to avoid precisely this kind of issue. `os.chdir` might be neccessary for somd particular problems, but specifying the full path of an image is not one of them.

Comment: actually i m new to python and cant understand what you said how to implement it , can you please add in my code what you said and how to implement it